# Spreading array of fns on compose results in "Expected 1 - 6 arguments, but got 0 or more"

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I understand that typescript sees a spread and assumes it can be of any length and that's why is complaining about having too many arguments (compose function arity is 1-6).

How can I satisfy the compiler when getting an array of functions on unknown length?

```js
import { compose } from "ramda";


//As long as the compiles is concerned fns might be any length (even more than 6)
const fns = [
    n => n * 10,
    n => n + 1,
  ]

const composed = compose(...fns) //Typescript: "Expected 1 - 6 arguments, but got 0 or more"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the compiler to know how many elements an array literal has, you might want to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to ask the compiler to infer it as a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple):

```
const fns = [
  (n: number) => n * 10,
  (n: number) => n + 1,
] as const;

/* const fns: readonly [(n: number) => number, (n: number) => number] */
```

(Also note that I am annotating the callback arguments as `number`, since otherwise you will get an implicit `any`, which you probably don't want).

Then `compose()` will work as expected:

```
const composed = compose(...fns); // no error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYwuCBnApnAvnAMyjTgCIoBDEAEwtIG4AoR1AOw3gPbgF44BtRnDgAKVgC44rAK4gARligBKXgD4pcAFRwAjAAYANENESpshcrUaA1LqMBdOBQwoI7GIwD02th0LtJKCwKajcAGwBPATFJGXlFFR51OIsDE1jzBKsUxUdNT2ZfeFR0bGpeV1KsEQA6Oq4MJSY4ISEgA)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround from [this thread](https://github.com/typed-typings/npm-ramda/issues/414):

```js
const composeList = list => R.reduceRight(R.compose,R.identity, list)

const composed = composeList(fns) //No longer upsets the compiler
composed(2) //=> 30
```

As I understand the snippet  above we're passing each item in the `list` to the `compose` function one by one. In this case `R.identity` in the middle will return the last function (either `fn[0]` in the array or a `compose(fn)` where `fn` is the composed version of the last fn.

It would be equivalent to `R.compose(R.compose(fns[0]),fns[1])` where it nests a compose for each item in the array. Since i'm calling each `compose` with 1 - 2  arguments it no longer upsets the compiler.

Comment: Now you're just bounded by your stack size. The list cannot be longer than the number of stack frames your JS interpreter will allow.